# TestDome: my solution works but I am only getting %50 right and not %100?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is the scenario question:

A frog only moves forward, but it can move in steps 1 inch long or in jumps 2 inches long. A frog can cover the same distance using different combinations of steps and jumps.

Write a function that calculates the number of different combinations a frog can use to cover a given distance.

For example, a distance of 3 inches can be covered in three ways: step-step-step, step-jump, and jump-step.

```
public class Frog{
public static int numberOfWays(int input) {

    int counter = 2;

    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 1 ; i< input -1; i++ ){

        x = i + counter;
        counter = x; 
    }
    if (input <3){
        x = input;

    }
    return x;

  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(numberOfWays(10));
 }
}
```

This solution only gives me %50 right not sure why its not %100 right, I tested it with other values and returns the right results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think recursion is a nice way to solve problems like that

```
public int numberOfCombinations(int distance) {
    if (distance == 1) {
        return 1; //step
    } else if (distance == 2) {
        return 2; // (step + step) or jump
    } else {
        return numberOfCombinations(distance - 1) + numberOfCombinations(distance - 2); 
       // we jumped or stepped into the current field
    }
}
```

Comment: oh right thanks for that, but this is going to take me time to understand how the process works. Can you advise any material on this topic?

Comment: Well you can google anything about "recursion", which is basically calling the function from its own body. I'm not sure I can recommend a single good resource about the topic for you. It may be also worth knowing that the solution for the problem you specified is exactly the same as for computing the n-th Fibonacci number, so you can also search for that.

Comment: oh haha I didn't realize i thought that was the pattern but I was wrong. I guess I will have to look into recursions in more detail; not my favorite topic but I have no choice.

Comment: Really nice code a bit slow due to the recursion but the solution is genius.+1

Comment: @Sun_Sparxz The solution is quite elegant and readable but it is surely not the most optimal one when it comes to performance. One reason is that every computation can be performed multiple times in this approach as the results of function calls are not cached (memoized).

Answer (score 4):

Let `f[n]` be the number of combinations of steps and jumps such that you travel `n` inches. You can immediately see that `f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2]`, that is first you can travel `n-1` inches in some way and then use 1 step or you can travel `n-2` inches in some way and then use 1 jump. Since `f[1] = 1` and `f[2] = 2` you can see that `f[n] = fib(n+1)`, the `n+1`-th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). You can calculate it in [linear time](http://proval.lri.fr/gallery/FibonacciJava.en.html) if it suits the purpose or, more efficiently, you can calculate it in `log n` time - [reference](http://kukuruku.co/hub/algorithms/the-nth-fibonacci-number-in-olog-n)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a modified version of the Fibonacci series. I get 100% for the following (sorry it's C# but is very similar):

```
using System;

public class Frog
{
    public static int NumberOfWays(int n)
    {

        int firstnumber = 0, secondnumber = 1, result = 0;  

            if (n == 1) return 1;
            if (n == 2) return 2;


            for (int i = 2; i <= n + 1; i++)  
            {  
                result = firstnumber + secondnumber;  
                firstnumber = secondnumber;  
                secondnumber = result;  
            }  

            return result;  

    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfWays(3));
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfWays(4));
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfWays(5));
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfWays(6));
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfWays(7));
        Console.WriteLine(NumberOfWays(8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think overlapping subproblem / dynamic programming. You need to memorize the repetitive calls to the sub-problem which will save you all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should cover your all scenarios.

```
    public static string numberOfCombinations(int distance) 
    {
        if (distance == 1) {
            return "Step";//1
        } else if (distance == 2) {
            return "Jump";//2
        } else{
            return numberOfCombinations(1) + numberOfCombinations(distance - 1); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, it returns only 1 combination (StepJump) for the input distance = 3 offered by the OP.